# SQLite drop column routine

Tags: sqlite

I need to write a DROP COLUMN routine for manipulating SQLite databases.

It would be called something like this:

```
dropColumn("SomeTable", "SomeColumn");
```

The SQLite FAQ says that to drop a column, you have to create a temporary table containing just the columns you want, and then copy the data across to it, and then rename it.

It shouldn't be too hard to encapsulate that into a routine. But it looks like it would be kind of annoying to write it.

Surely someone out there has written such a routine already. If so, can I steal it please? :)

Comment: It's basically dependant on what platform you will deploy SQLite on. Unless you want to recompile SQlite with the routine inside?

Comment: @MPelletier, the platform is .Net. But I figure the code should easily portable to any other modern platform. It should just involve executing some SQL and doing some string manipulation.

Comment: in that case, yeah. One thing to use to easily recreate the table without parsing the original `Create Table` is `PRAGMA table_info`.

Comment: @MPelletier, thanks, that does look useful.

Answer (score 5):

Here's some pseudo code for you:

```
columnNameList = ""
newTableStr = "CREATE TABLE tempMyTable ("
execute statement: "PRAGMA table_info('MyTable')"
While looping through RecordSet
  If RecordSet.name != tableRowToDeleteName
    If columnNameList != "" Then columnNameList += ","
    columnNameList += RecordSet.name

    newTableStr += RecordSet.name + " " + RecordSet.type
    If RecordSet.notnull Then
      newTableStr += " NOT NULL"
    End If
    If RecordSet.dflt_value != "" Then
      newTableStr += " DEFAULT(" + RecordSet.dflt_value + ")"
    End If
    If Not Last Record in RecordSet
      newTableStr += ","
    End If
  End If
End Loop
newTableStr += ");"

execute statement: newTableStr
execute statement: "INSERT INTO tempMyTable (" + columnNameList + ")" + 
                   "SELECT " + columnNameList + " FROM MyTable;"

Delete table: MyTable
Rename Table: tempMyTable to MyTable
```

Comment: Don’t forget the indexes and triggers on the table!  `DROP TABLE` also drops the attending indexes, triggers and foreign keys.  You can use `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type != 'table' AND tbl_name = 'MyTable')` to get the CREATE statements for them.  Of course, if the trigger or index uses the deleted key, you’re in trouble...

Comment: @Martijn Thanks for the hints. I wrote this example off the top of my head so it's not complete nor was it intended to be. Hopefully it got the point across however.

Comment: @Sparausile: my comment wasn’t intended as criticism so much as providing more information.  Sorry if that wasn’t clear. :-)